# "setSelected" method of tableview cell not return perfect size of cell in iOS 13 and xcode 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibezierpath, ios13, xcode11

Actually i have a to apply shadow on view inside tableview cell. That view's height is dynamic (based on content) means tableview cell is self size cell. Before iOS 13 and xcode 11 my code works perfectly, beacuse "setSelected" method of tableview cell return perfect size of all subviews of cell. In iOS 13 and xcode 11, "setSelected" method of tableview cell return size of all subview same as set in xib.

Use below code to apply shadow on view:-

```
// Below method return correct size of view_margin (UIView) after content update in xcode 12 , but in xcode 13 below method return view_margin size same as size define in xib means not update size based on content 
// Below method is tableview cell method
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view_margin.bounds];
    self.view_margin.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.view_margin.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0);
    self.view_margin.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
    self.view_margin.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
    self.view_margin.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
}
```

This issue occur only in xcode 11 and iOS 13

Comment: does this work in previous builds before ios 13? if so probably the hierarchy  of the views changed following IOS 13, you will have to itrate through the subviews and then set the attributes

Comment: @AnjulaS. Yes, it's working fine before iOS 13. If you have any link or code then please help me.

Comment: @AnjulaS. Have you any solution about above issue then please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: can you show me where you  use `setSelected` at the moment?

Comment: @AnjulaS. i have update my question. please check it.

Comment: Put a break point in this method . , in ios 13 and some other version and see if the method returns 2 different values , also is the background color returned properly or the entire method doesnt seem to return the correct values

Comment: @AnjulaS. Let me check

Comment: @AnjulaS. setSelected method return correct background color. and also return correct width of "view_margin" but wrong height return

Comment: `self.view_margin.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0);`                     width and height returned by this method ? also width is returned as 0.0 ? what is the height returned as . ? also is it possible for you to attach two images of the difference?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated 
{

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view_margin.bounds];
            self.view_margin.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            self.view_margin.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0);
            self.view_margin.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
            self.view_margin.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
            self.view_margin.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    });

}
```